# extanding layout page and links on other pages

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using ejs for my node js project and using html template for views like that

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);  app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

I want to use layout.html for my other pages, how can I exdent it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use ejs or ejs local as engine.

In your app:

```
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

after it create template file as .ejs
and in your other .ejs files require template like this:

```
<% layout('template.ejs') -%>
```

Comment: is it imposibble with html engine?

Comment: never tried it but also never saw examples of such usage. But you can use ejs without any troubles - it's possible change your file extension from .html to .ejs and it will work

Comment: Yes, I did with that, but I just wanted to do with html view engine ((